# How to multiply and append div by changing its values with loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to **multiply** and **append** one **div** element by changing its values inside it with loop in Javascript. I receive **json array**. After that, I parse json array in **loop** and place in div elements by id. My purpose is I want to make a div for each user and place all of them under each other. In the end by pressing Download pdf I will download div element using **html2pdf** library. How Can I do this task using javascript.

Now result is like below:
[image: result image]

I want the same div for each json object inside json array. All of the divs are appended like below.
**The result page should like this:**
[image]

**index.html**

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-50 mb-50">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="download"> download pdf</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card" id="invoice">

                    <div class="card-body ml-3 mr-2 pt-0">

                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <h6 style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><strong>Contract <span>&#8470; </span><u id="user_dogovor"></u> </strong> </h6>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row my-row0 nopadding"> 
                            <div class="col-md-6" > 
                                <p style="float: left;  margin-bottom: 5px;">London st</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p style="float: right;  margin-bottom: 5px;">«____» ________________2021 year.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row row-beginning" >
                            <div class="col-sm" >
                                    <div class="text-sm-left">
                                        <p>If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators <b><u id="user_name"></u></b>, passport: <b><u id="user_passport"></u></b> given <b><u id="user_vidan_date"></u></b> year given <b><u id="user_kem_vidan"></u></b>, address: <b><u id="user_address"></u></b>,  It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable:
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm mydiv-menu">
                                <div class="text-sm-left">
                                    <p>1.1. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable 
                                    </p>

                                    <p>1.2  If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div> 

                </div>
            </div>

        </div> 

    </div>
```

**style.css**

```
        *{
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            line-height: 16px;
        }

        div.mydiv-menu{
            text-indent: 40px;
        }

        .row-beginning p{
            text-indent: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }

        .my-below p{
            text-indent: 40px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .my-row3 p{
            text-indent: 40px;
        }

        .mydiv-menu p{
            margin:0;
        }

        .my-row p{
            margin:0;
        }

        .my-row5 {
            margin-top:5px;
        }

        .my-row-mid {
            margin-top:5px;
        }

        .table-condensed{
          font-size: 10px;
        }

        .my-row4 p{
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

        h6{
            font-size:13px;
        }

        p{
            font-size: 14px;

        }

        th {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
```

**My js code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowObject.length; i++) {

    var counter = rowObject[i];

    var name = counter["dogovor_id"];
    var passport =  counter["passport"];
    var kogda_vidan = '16.02.2021';
    var vidan_date = '«' + kogda_vidan.substring(0,2) + '»' + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(3,5) + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(6,10);
    var kem_vidan =counter["kem_vidan"];
    var address_dostavki = counter["address"];
    var dogovor_id = 153;

    document.getElementById('user_name').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('user_passport').innerHTML = passport;
    document.getElementById('user_vidan_date').innerHTML = vidan_date;
    document.getElementById('user_kem_vidan').innerHTML = kem_vidan;
    document.getElementById('user_address').innerHTML = address_dostavki;
    document.getElementById('user_dogovor').innerHTML = dogovor_id;

}
```

Comment: What is `rowObject` and where does it come from?

Comment: ```rowObject``` is a json array. It keeps several users information. My purpose is to parse ```rowObject``` array and put values to HTML div

Comment: You need to generate the entire `<div class="card" id="invoice">` inside the for loop using js and then append it inside `<div class="col-md-12">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is because you are not creating another `div` element, all you are actually doing is replacing the content of the same elements over and over.  What you will need to do is append a new element and then from there update the content of that element with the relevant data.

The most readable way would be to generate the html on the server and then return that to the JS via a XHR call.

If that is not possible you can build the HTML using JS and then append that all as a single string to an element.

Something like:

HTML

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-50 mb-50">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="download"> download pdf</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" id="elementsToPdf">
            
        </div>

    </div> 

</div>
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < rowObject.length; i++) {

    var counter = rowObject[i];

    var name = counter["dogovor_id"];
    var passport =  counter["passport"];
    var kogda_vidan = '16.02.2021';
    var vidan_date = '«' + kogda_vidan.substring(0,2) + '»' + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(3,5) + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(6,10);

    var kem_vidan =counter["kem_vidan"];
    var address_dostavki = counter["address"];
    var dogovor_id = 153;

    var htmlString = '<div class="card" id="invoice">';
    htmlString += '<div class="card-body ml-3 mr-2 pt-0">';
    htmlString += '<div class="row justify-content-center">';
    htmlString += '<h6 style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><strong>Contract <span>&#8470; </span><u id="user_dogovor"> ' + name + ' </u> </strong> </h6> '
    htmlString += '</div>'
    htmlString += '<div class="row my-row0 nopadding"> <div class="col-md-6" > <p style="float: left;  margin-bottom: 5px;">London st</p></div><div class="col-md-6"><p style="float: right;  margin-bottom: 5px;">«____» ________________2021 year.</p></div></div>'
    htmlString += '</div>'
    
    //etc.
    document.getElementById('elementsToPdf').append(htmlString);
}
```

You will just need to complete the above code with the rest of your html and replace code where required as per the one example I gave here.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append for more information about the append and how it is used to solve your problem

A better solution would be if your server could return the complete HTML that you want to append to the element, this would make your code more readable.  Since we don't know more about your setup and solution this is the best I could do with your given example.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. In my case, appending html elements in js seems better. But I will also try ```XHR call``` method.

Comment: @Abdusoli please accept the answer if it works out for you

Comment: One more question, inside for loop, do I need to change ```id``` values also? I mean one ```id``` should be unique in entire page

Comment: Seems like you forgot ```.innerHTML``` when appending

Comment: That is possible, was doing this out of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing what you asked, much less elegant and prone to XSS attacks, choice is yours:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-50 mb-50">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="download"> download pdf</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 target-div">
                
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
function generateCard(name, passport, kogdaVidan, vidanDate, kemVidan, addressDostavki, dogovorId) {
    const targetDiv = document.querySelector('.target-div');

    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.id = 'invoice';
    card.innerHTML = `
        <div class="card-body ml-3 mr-2 pt-0">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <h6 style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><strong>Contract <span>&#8470; </span><u id="${dogovorId}"></u> </strong> </h6>
            </div>

            <div class="row my-row0 nopadding"> 
                <div class="col-md-6" > 
                    <p style="float: left;  margin-bottom: 5px;">London st</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p style="float: right;  margin-bottom: 5px;">${vidanDate}</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row row-beginning" >
                <div class="col-sm" >
                        <div class="text-sm-left">
                            <p>If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators <b><u id="user_name"></u></b>, passport: <b><u id="user_passport"></u></b> given <b><u id="user_vidan_date"></u></b> year given <b><u id="user_kem_vidan"></u></b>, address: <b><u id="user_address"></u></b>,  It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable:
                            </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm mydiv-menu">
                    <div class="text-sm-left">
                        <p>1.1. There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable 
                        </p>
                        <p>1.2  If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
    targetDiv.appendChild(card);
}

for (let i = 0; i < rowObject.length; i++) {
    const counter = rowObject[i];
    const name = counter["dogovor_id"];
    const passport =  counter["passport"];
    const kogda_vidan = '16.02.2021';
    const vidan_date = '«' + kogda_vidan.substring(0,2) + '»' + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(3,5) + ' ' + kogda_vidan.substring(6,10);
    const kem_vidan =counter["kem_vidan"];
    const address_dostavki = counter["address"];
    const dogovor_id = 153;

    generateCard(name, passport, kogda_vidan, vidan_date, kem_vidan, address_dostavki, dogovor_id);
};
```

By the way, you need to pass the other parameters where needed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try it

Comment: With this approach you will not need the id at all since you are setting the values in line as part of the loop